# How to refresh input with every enter press and/or callback variable/function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```js
let myInput = document.querySelector(".input");
let myOutput = document.querySelector(".result");

let sudo = false;
let isGood = false;
let enter = false;
let repeat = 
      '<div class="content2">'
      + '<div class="linia">'
      + '<span id="terminal2">linux@love:~</span>'
      +'<input type="text" class="input" size="50">'
      +'</div>'
      +'<div class="result"></div>'
      +'</div>';

myInput.disabled = false;
let cA = [
    ["mkdir", "creates new dir"],
    ["userdel", "deletes user"],
    ["useradd", "adds user"]
]  

const listHelp = function(command)
{
    if(command == "help" || command == "HELP")
        {
            for(let i=0; i<cA.length; i++){
              //  console.log(cA[i][0]);
            myOutput.innerHTML += '<span>' + (cA[i][0]) + '</span><br />';
            }
            myOutput.innerHTML += repeat;
            myInput = document.querySelector(".input");
            return inputValue;
        }
    else{
        myOutput.innerHTML += '<span>' + "Error" +'</span><br />';
        myOutput.innerHTML += repeat;
        return checkCMD;
    }
    
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------*/
const commandList = function (command){
    console.log(command);
    if(sudo == true)
    {
    command = command.replace("sudo ", "");
    console.log(command);
    }
        for (let i = 0; i<cA.length; i++)
      {
            if(cA[i].includes(command) == true){
               console.log(cA [i][1]);
               isGood = true;
                myOutput.innerHTML += '<span>' + cA [i][1] + '</span><br />';
        
                break;
          }
      }
    if(isGood == true){
         myOutput.innerHTML += repeat;
    }
    else{return listHelp(command);}
}
const isSudo = function (checkSudo){
    if (checkSudo.startsWith("sudo") == true)
        {
            console.log(checkSudo);
            sudo = true;
            return commandList(checkSudo) + sudo;
        }
    else{
        console.log("Nie sudo");
        return commandList(checkSudo);
    }
} 

const isEnter = function (checkEnter){
    if (checkEnter.keyCode === 13)
        {
            inputValue = myInput.value;
            console.log("Enter");
            myInput.disabled = true;
            console.log(inputValue);
            return isSudo(inputValue);
            }
        }
const checkCMD = myInput.addEventListener("keypress", isEnter);
```

```css
html{
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

}
body{
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.konsola{

width:500px;
height:300px;
color:#71a33b;
position:absolute;
border-radius:1%;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
//float:left;
//z-index: 3;
}
#terminal2::selection{
background:black;
color:white;
}
.pasek{
font-weight:100;
background:linear-gradient(#616161, #353535);
box-shadow: black 0px 1.7px 4px -0.7px;
color:white;
width:100%;
height:8%;
user-select:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.zamknij{
position:relative;
background-color:darkorange;
color:gray;
border-radius:100%;
width:13px;
height:13px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
line-height: 13px;
font-size:10px;
text-align:center;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    
}
.zamknij:hover{
background-color:orange;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.zamknij:active{
background-color:darkorange;
transition: .05s ease-in-out;
}
#minimalizuj{
position:relative;
background-color:#63625c;
color:gray;
border-radius:100%;
width:13px;
height:13px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
line-height: 11px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
#minimalizuj:hover{
background-color:orange;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
#minimalizuj:active{
background-color:darkorange;
transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
#maksymalizuj{
position:relative;
background-color:#63625c;
color:gray;
border-radius:100%;
width:13px;
height:13px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:5px;
line-height: 10px;
font-size:13px;
text-align:center;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
#maksymalizuj:hover{
background-color:orange;
transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
#maksymalizuj:active{
background-color:darkorange;
transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
#terminal{
margin:7px;
line-height:9px;
font-size:15px;
float:left;
}
#terminal2{
position:relative;
line-height:9px;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:700;
left: 5px;
top: 10px;
    float:left;
    
}
.content{
    background-color:#39152e;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.content2{
    background-color:#39152e;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.wynik{
color:red;    
}
textarea, #odmowa{
position:relative;
background:none;
border:none;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
color:white;
resize:none;
font-size:15px;
width: 78%;
line-height:17px;
//margin-top:13px;
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;
top:4px;
    left:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}
textarea::selection , #odmowa::selection, .wynik::selection{
        background-color: black;
    color:white;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
border-radius:50px;
width:4px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color:orange;
    border-radius:50px;
}


.linia{
    position:relative;
   width:100%; 
    height:30px;
    top:1px;
}
#odmowa{
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Konsola</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="konsola.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu|Ubuntu+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="konsola">
 <div class="pasek">
  <div class="zamknij">X</div>
  <div id="minimalizuj">-</div>
  <div id="maksymalizuj">□</div>
  <span id="terminal">linux@love:~</span>
 </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="linia">
      <span id="terminal2">linux@love:~</span>
      <!--<textarea spellcheck="false" class="input" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea>-->
          <input type="text" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
   <script language="javascript" src="konsola2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

After few days of thinking and making my code I'm finally stuck. I want to make Terminal.

Type help to see commands, and then try to enter one of them. It's impossible, `myInput.value` doesn't refresh itself or just checkCMD isn't called again.

My question is: how to call checkCMD after first input / or how to refresh 
`myInput.value`
to change every time user type some text. Should I delete its content in any function? I don't expect ready code from you, just small hint with description.

Sorry for nooby question and mess in my code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here (not a link) - preferably a working snippet.  Also read [ask].

Comment: @Archer is it good now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event listener is always listening for keypress of your first `.input` element (even when it becomes `disabled`).

So in your loop you'll have to select newly created element (by using `querySelectorAll` and selecting last one, or `myInput = document.querySelector(".input:not(:disabled)");` to select not disabled one. Then add new event listener to this element: `myInput.addEventListener("keypress", isEnter);`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for quick and accurate answer. It works almost perfect. Almost because I have something wrong with code and now it repeats help command, but when I type mkdir - enter and after that again help it shows nothing just linux@love. It doesn't list available commands. And also command you have entered disappears. And if I understand everything... I should place 

myInput = document.querySelector(".input:not(:disabled)");
myInput.addEventListener("keypress", isEnter);

in both loops? (Help loop and commandList loop)

Comment: I have worked out why help was messed. Now I must set command visible and improve some css code. Huge thanks!